# Extended continuous linear transformation keeping same norm , when co domain is finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a real normed linear space $X$ , $T:Y \to \mathbb R^n$ be a continuous linear transformation ; then can we extend $T$ to a continuous linear transformation $\bar T : X \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $||T||=||\bar T||$ ?

What I have thought is : If $p_j$ is $j$-th co-ordinate projection of $\mathbb R^n$ , then for each $j$ , we get a continuous functional $p_j\circ T:Y \to \mathbb R$ , so by Hahn-Banach , we get an extended continuous linear functional $T_j:X \to \mathbb R$ with $||p_j \circ T||=||T_j||$ for each $j$ ; then $\bar T(x):=(T_1(x), ..., T_n(x))$ is a continuous extension of $T$ ; but I don't know whether it preserves norm or not . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: If you put on $\mathbb R^n$ the max-norm you see easily that $\lVert \hat T \rVert \leq \lVert T \rVert$. You can use submultiplicativity of the norm and that $\lVert p_i \rVert \leq 1$.

Comment: @Epsilon : Yes , I can see that now ; and since $\bar T$ is an extension of $T$ , obviously $||T|| \le ||\bar T||$ , right ?